# Why my ajax could not execute perl

Tags: ajax, perl

I can't execute perl by ajax. 
Why the responseText always returns the entire perl codes?

The following example is to get data from perl. The response I get from function updateTime is the entire perl code.

BTW: I can execute the perl code in cmd window using command "c:/perl/bin/perl test.cgi".

The JS code is as below:

```
function updateTime(){

 var xmlhttp_t = createXMLHTTPRequest();
 xmlhttp_t.open("GET","cgi-bin/test.cgi",false);
 xmlhttp_t.send();
 if(xmlhttp_t.readyState == 4){
   return xmlhttp_t.responseText;
 }
}

//
//Get XMLHttpRequest
//
function createXMLHTTPRequest(){
var xhr_object = null;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xhr_object = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if(window.ActiveXOject)
{
    xhr_object = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
else
{
    alert("Your browser doesn't provide XMLHttpRequest functionality");
    return;
}
return xhr_object;
}
```

The Perl code is as below:

```
#!c:/perl/bin/perl

use strict;
use CGI;
use warnings;

my $cgi = new CGI();
print $cgi->header('text/html; charset=UTF-8');

print "aaaa";
```

Comment: You have to set up your server to be able to run perl scripts

Comment: @Musa Thank you for reminding. That is true. Because I run .cgi outside the cgi-bin folder, I need to add a file .htaccess including two lines "AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
    
Options +ExecCGI".

Answer (score 3):

> The response I get from function updateTime is the entire perl code.

Then it's a server configuration issue.

[Documentation for Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html)

Comment: Thank you @ikegami , the .htaccess files really helps!